# wp_get_post_terms Order by not working

Tags: plugin-development, functions, query, terms

wp_get_post_terms Order by not working

My code is here

```
query_posts(array('post_type' => 'product','post__in' => $product_ids,));

while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    global $post;

$args = array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all');
$product_terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'productcategory',$args);
if(!empty($product_terms)){
  if(!is_wp_error( $product_terms )){
    echo '<ul>';
    foreach($product_terms as $term){
      echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, 'product').'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>'; 
    }
    echo '</ul>';
  }
}

endwhile;
```

I read read on the documentation that its support array $args to make order the terms by "name", ASC however I don't know why it wont work

Answer (score 4):

Your title is

```
wp_get_post_terms Order by not working
```

but if you use a custom post type you need to use `wp_get_object_terms()`

I'm not sure what your aim is, but here is a code example you can try:

```
$my_post_type="post"; // edit this 
$my_taxonomy="category"; // edit this

$my_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => $my_post_type,'posts_per_page'=>10));

if ($my_query->have_posts()) : 
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); 
        $product_terms = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), $my_taxonomy, array('orderby' => 'name', 'order' => 'ASC', 'fields' => 'all'));
        if(!empty($product_terms)){
            if(!is_wp_error( $product_terms )){
                echo '<ul>';
                foreach($product_terms as $term){
                    echo '<li><a href="'.get_term_link($term->slug, $my_taxonomy).'">'.$term->name.'</a></li>'; 
                }
            echo '</ul><hr>';
        }
    }
    endwhile;
endif;
```

ps: I changed your code a bit, so now we use `WP_Query()` instead of the non-recommended  `query_posts()`.

**Edit:**

Here is an example of the output, where the terms are ordered with `name` and `ASC`

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
---
aaa
ccc
---
bbb
ccc
```

and with order `DESC`

```
ccc
bbb
aaa
---
ccc
aaa
---
ccc
bbb
```

Comment: not working , what I wanted to achieve is to make product term order by name ASC

Comment: I updated the code so you can test it with custom post type `post` and taxonomy `category` to debug it. This code example works on my install. I changed DESC to ASC for the terms order. What is your taxonomy name and custom post type name (`product`?)

Comment: It doesn't work either, I have custome post type product and taxonomy product term, what I want is to order post product taxonomy in ASC order

Comment: Do you get any output or is it empty? You could try `var_dump($my_query);` to see if the query is also empty. Do you have a space in your taxonomy name: `product term` or is it also `product`?

Comment: nope I get output but unorderd, I get all product categories that selected on each post but  each post dont have ordered productegory they selected, I dont even have space on my product term or product

Comment: I updated the answer with the term output on my install. Do you see any change when you switch from ASC to DESC?